# Daily quota exceeded - Google places API Nearby Search request

Tags: android, google-places-api, quota

I know this has been asked before but I haven't quite understood how to fix it...

I'm building an app that shows a list of nearby restaurants. I'm using google places API and the nearby search request for that.

It works fine, but sometimes I get this:

```
{
   "error_message":"You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http:\/\/g.co\/dev\/maps-no-account",
   "html_attributions":[

   ],
   "results":[

   ],
   "status":"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

I know I have several free requests to do daily and I'm pretty sure I haven't spend them all...

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I think , you have to add billing details even to use free usages

Comment: Yes, after google developer policies update you need to add your billing details to use APIs.

Comment: But that will make me accept the 300$ they are giving right? :(

Comment: checkout, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016872/google-places-api-quota-exceed

Comment: You need to enable billing, but that doesn't necessarily mean you'll be charged. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315686/11742502